# document selector on multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, selector

so we can write a function on `keyup` by using Jquery on:

```
$('#thing').on('keyup',function(){
    //code goes here
});
```

but, if you want to use ajax or create the `#thing` dynamically in javascript, then this will not work.

In an instance where one dynamically creates an element like that, you use the `document`. The following would be used:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#thing',function(){
    //code goes here
});
```

**But what if we want multiple events???**

The non-dynamic version is allowed. Let's say we want keyup and keypress:

```
$('#thing').on('keyup keypress',function(){
    //code goes here
});
```

but the dynamic version below will not work:

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress','#thing',function(){
    //code goes here
});
```

**how can one use `$(document).on` for multiple events on a specific selector? if it is not possible, what would be the equivalent enabling dynamic creation?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me in chrome. Are you sure your element created triggers the events you are binding to? Might also be a browser compatibility issue.

```
$('body').append('<input type="text" id="thing" placeholder="thing">');


$(document).on('keyup keypress','#thing',function(){
   alert('event tiggered');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aY29a/